# Is there an async API for MS Office /VBA Word object model?

Tags: vba, vsto, ms-word, ole

I'd like to export a Word document to an HTML file. There are methods (`SaveAs` and `ExportAsFixedFormat`) on the [Document object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822963.aspx) in the Microsoft Word object model to do that but they are all synchronous API.

I can't find an `async` version for the Word API. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do one thing at a time per Word.Application via Interop, but depending on your scenario, you can use several application objects and the multithreading capabilities of .NET

Comment: I understand that. The thing is: saving a file, for example, is one atomic operation as per the current synchronous API. It is done via a call to the `Document.SaveAs` method. I do not see how I can turn it into an asynchronous call. The only thing I can do is queue the saving of the file on the task pool, which, anyways, is a bad idea since it is an I/O bound / threadless operation. I was wondering if there was an async API with cancellation tokens and progress and all, I could take finer grained control over the file saving operation.